# How to integrate google analytics with electron?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, electron, firebase-analytics, capacitor

We are creating a desktop app with ionic/capacitor which uses electron.
We want to integrate analytics for this desktop version and understood firebase does not support.
What are the other options we have to implement this. We currently don't have approval for GA4

Answer (score 0):

The [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) can be used to send hits to Google analytics.

If your electron is off line remember to keep track of the [qt](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#qt) parameter or the dates and times will be wrong.

Comment: In case you have GA4 account and do not have UA-XXXX tacking id, you can use this guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#send_an_event

Comment: @JúliusSkrisa and how can you setup the GA4 data stream for your Electron app to actually _listen_ to the POST request described there? (afaic you can choose only web or ios/andriod app)

Comment: @pergy does GA4 support data streams like that?